# How to save chunked Xarray data into single zarr file, not multiple files?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-xarray, chunks

I am busy processing a large amount of atmospheric data. The file has dimensions Time:5200000, south_north:434, west_east:653.

It has the following coordinates: Time, lat, lon.

I want to map power curves to wind speed and for each time point, south_north and west_east combination. I think chunks of South_north=20 and west_east=20 are good. At the end of the processing, I would like to have a single file directory, lets call it Power_curve which is a zarr file containing the output of the above.

At the moment I am only able to store the processed chunks individual, not as one larger file.

Here is the code

```
# Define the chunk size for each dimension
chunk_size = {'south_north': 20, 'west_east': 20}

# Calculate the number of chunks for each dimension
num_chunks = {dim: int(np.ceil(len(ds[dim]) / chunk_size[dim])) for dim in chunk_size}

# Initialize a list to store the paths of the chunks
chunk_paths = []

for i in range(num_chunks['south_north']):
    for j in range(num_chunks['west_east']):
        
        # Calculate the slice for this chunk
        slice_south_north = slice(i*chunk_size['south_north'], (i+1)*chunk_size['south_north'])
        slice_west_east = slice(j*chunk_size['west_east'], (j+1)*chunk_size['west_east'])
        
        # Extract the chunk from the dataset
        subset = ds.sel(Time=slice(None), south_north=slice_south_north, west_east=slice_west_east)

        # Perform the calculation for this chunk
        ws = np.sqrt(np.square(subset.U) + np.square(subset.V))
        WH = np.ceil(ws * 2) / 2
        WL = np.floor(ws * 2) / 2
        Rho_H = (np.ceil(subset.RHO * 40) / 40)
        Rho_L = (np.floor(subset.RHO * 40) / 40)
        
        WH= WH.where(WH > 3.0, 0)
        WH= WH.where(WH<24.5,24.5)
        
        WL= WL.where(WL > 3, 0)
        WL= WL.where(WL<24.5,24.5)

        Rho_L= Rho_L.where(Rho_L > 0.95, 0.95)
        Rho_L= Rho_L.where(Rho_L< 1.275, 1.275)
        
        Rho_L=Rho_L.astype(str)

        # Assuming da is already defined and it's a lookup table
        da.sel(row=WH, column=Rho_L)
        power = (power / 2)
        power.name = 'Power_Curve'
        power_curve_dataset = power.to_dataset()

        # Define the path for this chunk
        chunk_path = f"S:\\uv_ds_120m_with_density\\chunks\\power_curve_dataset_{i}_{j}.zarr"

        # Save the chunk to a zarr file
        power_curve_dataset.to_zarr(chunk_path, mode='w')
        
        # Store the chunk path
        chunk_paths.append(chunk_path)
```

At the end of this process I end up with over 600 sub-files of each chunk. So not what I am looking for. It is important for me to retain the dimensions in the order found in the original file, as there is another script I use to map actual coordinates to south_north/west_east points.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try storing all chunks in a list, then after it is done computing concatenate them along the south_north nd west_east dimension using `xarray.concat`. Afterwards just save the data at once in the zarr file.

Comment: Thanks Eric. 

I have it running but I am running out of RAM by looking at the Dask status. Is this an issue of available RAM at the end of the day or the size of my chunks. 

Not a Computer Scientist so understand a little but it's also a feeling of Alice going down the rabbit hole